# Can't print to console from within while-loop in R

Tags: r, loops, console, output

I am running this piece of code from a Rgui.exe window in Windows:

```
i = 1
while(i <= 10){
    cat(i, "\n") 
    i = i + 1
    Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

The cat() piece does not get output every 2 seconds, but only collectively at the end of the 20 seconds, i.e. 10 iterations.

I am used to print() and cat() calls getting output immediately, so I don't know why this is happening here.

How do I make R print immediately in each iteration?

Comment: It works for me. What system/R are you using? Anyway, consider using `message` here instead, which seems more appropriate for progress messages etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "output buffering"; try `flush.console()` after using `cat`. From the help page:

> This does nothing except on console-based versions of R. On the macOS
>   and Windows GUIs, it ensures that the display of output in the console
>   is current, even if output buffering is on.